# Is there a way to submit new closed form solutions to Wolfram?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, summation

I seem to keep coming across formulae that are not evaluated by Mathematica. For instance, today I was checking

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^n+1}$$
(from this year's Putnam competition), which I can prove is equal to $1$. However, Mathematica can not evaluate this sum symbolically (at least not directly using any simplification methods I know of). I have seen similar sums and (double) integrals in the past with proven closed form solutions that also do not evaluate.

Is there some way of submitting closed form solutions to Wolfram if they can not be evaluated with Mathematica? Perhaps with a reference to the literature containing a proof of the new relation.

Edit: Fixed a typo in the exponent of the $-1$

Comment: BTW the sum equals $\color{red}{-}1$.

Comment: Have you tried simply contacting them?

Comment: Supporting statement by @AccidentalFourierTransform, `NSum[(-1)^k/k * Simplify[Sum[1/(k 2^n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}]], {k, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to `-1.`

Comment: I think this question is marginally off-topic here. There's no official way that I am aware of to report *specifically this*, but of course you can contact them: http://www.wolfram.com/support/.  I consider it off topic because your question is analogous to "What will Peter say if I ask him about X?"  Well, don't ask us, ask Peter directly!

Comment: Indeed, the original exponent on the $-1$ in my notes was $k-1$, so the answer should actually be $-1$. I was wondering if there was a more official or preferred way of submitting results such as this, but I suppose there is not.

Comment: Contact support@wolfram.com. Please also be clear that you are making a suggestion. If they mistake your email for a request for help, which happens, that will complicate things.